# How To Verify The Code Of A SmartContract?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, cardano-node, on-chain, verification

There's a lot of talk about open-source code on Cardano, but how can I verify that the SmartContract(s) in a git repo are the actual SmartContracts the project has deployed to the Blockchain?

I want to know this for two reasons:

1. Make sure I'm not staking my ADA in a SmartContract that looks perfect on GitHub, but has a backdoor (to steal my ADA) onchain.
2. So other people can verify my code

Can I do this using the Cardano Node from the Ubuntu CLI?

Comment: You do not need the node, you need GHC and some plutus dependencies to compile it. Do you have a source that you want to check?

Comment: No, I got it just thought, it might be a good question to have on here for new learners. For some reason theres not really an easy way in for new guys yet, but it has gotten a lot better

Comment: Have you deployed the smart contract?

Comment: I have quite a few smart contracts deployed, but this is a general question, not targeting any particular SC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compile the code yourself to see if the address you arrive at aligns with what's live.

Comment: I know this is the correct answer but on the other hand I understand this is also not acceptable for the standard user and it sucks compared to other blockchains.

Comment: Well you can always trust a block explorer with such features like etherscan(or other centralised/trusted data providers) to feed you the truth, like other blockchains do.

Comment: This might be a pay-to-verify service later on. Who knows but it would really help build trust.